# How to make microk8s ctr image prune

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-image, microk8s

I'm getting a low disk space warning on a server where my microk8s and applications are installed. When I run the microk8s ctr image ls command, multiple images appear for an application. Does the "docker image prune -f" command in Docker have an equivalent in microk8s? Or is there a way possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to delete all custom added images from the built-in library, you can do this:

```
# get all images that start with localhost:32000, output the results into image_ls file
sudo microk8s ctr images ls name~='localhost:32000' | awk {'print $1'} > image_ls 
# loop over file, remove each image
cat image_ls | while read line || [[ -n $line ]];
do
    microk8s ctr images rm $line
done;
```

Put it into a .sh file and run the script

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

`sudo crictl rmi --prune`

to remove unused images (that's because `crictl` is compatible with `containerd`).

---

Instructions:

1. [Install](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cri-tools/blob/edf14e37007994d69f9b8cb3b1483a79b365b8eb/docs/crictl.md#install-crictl) `crictl`.
2. Configure `crictl`, adapting [k8s crictl setup docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-cluster/crictl/) to `microk8s` (by using the actual location of `containerd.sock` valid for `microk8s`, which is `unix:///var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd.sock`).
3. Check if `crictl` is working against microk8s's `containerd` socket: `sudo crictl images`
4. To prune unused images:

```
sudo crictl rmi --prune
```

Answer (score 0):

A one liner:

```
sudo microk8s ctr i ls name~='localhost:32000' -q|while read z;do sudo microk8s ctr i rm $z;done
```

You can remove the filter `name~='localhost:32000'` or use it to match specific tag you want to clean up, example: `name~=':v5.2.0'`.

**NOTE: If no filter is specified, all local images will be removed**